# Checking mail on mobile data

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, mobile-network

i use roaming which is very expensive and I search some kind of script or way of solving my problem: there is a possibility to **turn off** checking e-mail when the android is connected via mobile data ? Any knows how to limit the transfer of mobile data to the minimum (disable apps which I do not want sync etc.) ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Could you not set your email settings to fetch rather then push? That way it will only update when you open the email application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go into Settings -> Data Usage you can see which apps are using the most data. It's possible to turn them off using data in the background by clicking on the app and then selecting "Restrict Background Data". See [this](http://howto.cnet.com/2300-11310_39-10017951-3.html) and [this](http://www.pocketables.com/2013/08/android-tip-control-background-data-usage-for-individual-apps.html) for pictures and further detail.

Also if it's just email you're using you can probably turn it off automatically checking depending on the client and email service you're using. If you're using Gmail then go into the Gmail app, go to the settings for your account and turn off "Sync Gmail".

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer ! It is very helpfull ! I check it tomorrow. I installed https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobidia.android.mdm&hl=pl and i see that the more transfer took OS Services and i do not know how to block it.

Comment: Yeah, now it works very good ! Thanks ! ! ! ! What a pity I cannot click thumb UP..

Answer (score 2):

Next to the settings pointed out by [Peanut's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/56002/16575), it might be worth to check some special roaming apps like e.g. [Roaming Control](http://www.appbrain.com/app/roaming-control/com.insadco.roamingcontrol):

> Roaming Control automatically enables or disables mobile data connection, airplane mode or **auto sync** based on the currently active network operator.

(emphasis mine). If your mail client obeys the sync settings, this should be an excellent alternative: have it checking mails in background usually, but just not while in roaming. Best explained by a screenshot:

[image: Roaming Control]
<sup>*Roaming Control* (click for larger variant)</sup>